# momentjs display in timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone, sheetjs

I am desperate. I am located in Germany.

I am getting a Date object from Sheetjs. 
In Excel I see a date like 05. March 2020.
I just need a string like 2020-03-05.

This date gives me:

```
console.log(maximalesBelegdatumJS);
console.log(moment(maximalesBelegdatumJS));
console.log(moment(maximalesBelegdatumJS).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

The output is:

```
Wed Mar 04 2020 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: Wed Mar 04 2020 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit), _isUTC: true, _offset: -0, _pf: {…}, …}_isAMomentObject: true_i: Wed Mar 04 2020 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit) {}_isUTC: true_offset: -0_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _ordinal: "%d.", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}\./, …}_z: Zone {name: "UTC", abbrs: Array(1), untils: Array(1), offsets: Array(1), population: 0}_d: Wed Mar 04 2020 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit) {}_isValid: true__proto__: Object
2020-03-04
```

I have tried lots of modifiers, like `.utc()`, `.local()` but I just don't get it.

One solution I found (but **I think is a hack**) is to add the `utcOffset`:

```
console.log(moment(maximalesBelegdatumJS).add(moment(maximalesBelegdatumJS).utcOffset(), "minute"));
```

giving

```
Moment
_isAMomentObject: true
_i: Wed Mar 04 2020 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit) {}
_isUTC: false
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _ordinal: "%d.", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}\./, …}
_d: Thu Mar 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit) {}
_isValid: true
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Is your original data in Central European standard time?  Assuming you have moment-timezone installed:

https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/.

```
console.log(moment.tz(maximalesBelegdatumJS, 'CET').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Or replace 'CET' with the original timezone the data is in.  I think what was happening is that the dates were not initialized with the proper timezone and this is causing the conversion issues.

If this does not work, can you post the ISO string of the original variable "maximalesBelegdatumJS"?  Maybe there is an issue not with moment.

Interesting, for some reason the original datetime is initialized in UTC, then the tz attribute is changed to CET without actually converting the datetime. I never used SheetJs but something is going on there.

You already alluded to the answer with utcOffset():

```
console.log(moment(maximalesBelegdatumJS).utcOffset(2).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

This would be a more simple version.

Comment: This is the console log of the js date: `Wed Mar 04 2020 23:00:00 GMT+0100`. Your tz-solution unfortunately does not work.

Comment: I guess the input date is just wrong. But it's an export I have to influence on...

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is this:

```
var solution = moment(maximalesBelegdatumJS);
solution.add(solution.utcOffset(), "minute")
console.log(solution);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the date constructed by SheetJS is treating the input as UTC, but you were creating your strings based on the local-time equivalent.

You can simply keep it in UTC when generating the string:

```
moment.utc(maximalesBelegdatumJS).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

- `moment.utc(dateObject)` creates a `Moment` from the same timestamp as the `Date` object, and sets the Moment object to UTC mode.
- `.format('YYYY-MM-DD')` creates a string output in the format you asked for.

I'll also point out another way you could handle this, that doesn't require Moment at all.

```
maximalesBelegdatumJS.toISOString().substring(0, 10)
```

- `.toISOString()` creates an ISO 8601 date and time string in UTC - which matches the way the `Date` object was created.
- `.substring(0, 10)` gives you just the date portion, in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.